# How to select a item in a Dictionary, using a list box

Tags: c#, .net

I have a listBox visually representing the items in a Dictionary. The Dictionary contains a custom class called Contact.

I want to use the strings in the listBox (which are the same as a Dicitonary reference) to refer to the Contact contained in the Dictionary. I am having trouble getting this working, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as the text of the listBox is the key of the item in the dictionary, things should be fairly straightforward. (i may have mucked up the property names here)

```
var contact = dict[listBox.SelectedItem];
```

Comment: ... or just `dict[listBox.SelectedItem]`

Comment: You put me on the right track, but I had to ad a ToString() to make it work.

Contacts[lbxContacts.SelectedItem.ToString()]

Answer (score 1):

The listbox can be databound to the keys property of the Dictionary.  You can then get the selected value of the list box and use that as a key to the dictionary to get the associated Contact object.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is that you can bind your dictionary to `DataSource` with proper `DisplayMember`, then just simply get whole `Contact` objects.